# searching partial word in Apache-Solr

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, solr

I have setup solr,and I want to search a word by providing charecter/s from that word.example :a word is "University" if I give "uni" it returns nothing. I used fieldtype is text. and defaultsearchfield is text and also copyfield is text.
Thank you. 
Noman

Answer (score 0):

Look at [wildcard searches](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html). In your particular case, the search query should be `uni*`.